# Trying to make two random outputs print onto one line

Tags: python, random

I am creating a program that randomly creates outfits one should wear, because the shirts and pants have to be chosen separately they print onto two lines in the code and I'd like some help getting them to print as one line to make it look less awkward, here's a sample of my code:

```
if choice == '111':
    mhbs = random.choice([ms1, ms2, ms3])
    if mhbs == ms1:
        ms1.explain()
    if mhbs == ms2:
        ms2.explain()
    if mhsb == ms3:
        ms3.explain()
    mhp = random.choice([mp1, mp2, mp3])
    if mhp == mp1:
        mp1.explain()
    if mhp == mp2:
        mp2.explain()
    if mhp == mp3:
        mp3.explain()
```

One example of how this would print is:

Wear a white, long sleeve shirt with

black jeans

The goal of how I would like it to print it:

Wear a white, long sleeve shirt with black jeans

Not too sure if I'll have to edit something within this code or within the part of the class where explain is defined. Please help!

Comment: What is the output of what you have so far?

Comment: @Jakub it'll print both answers on separate lines so it would say: wear a white, long sleeve shirt with (separate line) black jeans and it awkwardly splits the two up

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested):

```
if choice == '111':
    mhbs = random.choice([ms1, ms2, ms3])
    mhp = random.choice([mp1, mp2, mp3])
    print mhbs.explain(), mhb.explain()
```